# Kubernetes cannot access pods at slave node

Tags: kubernetes

I deployed Kubernetes with multiple master configuration from [kubadm multiple maser HA document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/). Then I join a worker node to this cluster.

At worker node, I could not ping ip of pods which were running at other nodes.
At each master node, I could ping other node's pods.

I also found that the cni0 interface not existed at worker nodes but existed at master nodes.

Did I miss any configurations?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, as you suspected, it's a failure to configure the CNI interface; you'll need to include more details about your _working_ CNI setup if you expect anyone to be able to help you. We're not psychic

Comment: When the slave just joins the cluaster by kubeadm command, cni0 is not created, I cannot ping pod running at master.
Then I assign a pod to slave, cni0 is created, and I can ping pod running at master.